# What's up with this green?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, meta, profile-page

[Sometime yesterday](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3107542#3107542), we got a new profile page on Meta and on the main site with some minor design tweaks to vote counts and reputation changes:

[image: Vote counts]

---

[image: Reputation changes]

I quite like these boxes (I guess [we gave away circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250479/i-want-the-old-good-star-back) to get them), and I assume they're part of an eventual migration of the [new profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) currently being showcased on Meta.SE (adding that the design would be partially pushed to Stack Overflow would have been nice).

However, I have just one question: why was this green (`#4ab471`) chosen for the "accepted" color in the Meta.SO variant of the design?

[image: #4ab471]

Why not the standard `#75845c` as used on the main site and previously here? It's driving [some people](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH4AX.png) crazy.

I could see why it would be used if it were carried over from the new M.SE profile directly, but I looked around, and I couldn't find this color anywhere else.

Comment: *Green?* That's clearly blue and black.

Comment: Looks white and gold to me...

Comment: @Shog9 Sounds like politics.

Comment: As you said, they're going to roll out a new profile page so the existing shade of green is probably going to get replaced with the new one.

Comment: @BSMP But why? That's not the green they used on M.SE or on SO.

Comment: Any *true Irishman* will tell you that if the foreground color is gold, the background better damned well be a shade of [leprechaun green.](http://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/paint-color/leprechaungreen)

Comment: @AstroCB Maybe they're doing some A/B testing with the colors? It would explain why you're only seeing the green in one place. Or maybe the contrast with the old colors is too low.

Comment: It's in preparation for St. Patrick's Day of course! Just because my birthday is in March doesn't mean that I'm not biased, er wait, what? Nevermind! Enjoy your green, back in my day we only had black, white, and two shades of grey and we were happy to have them! *old-codger-mode-off*

Comment: I find it a huge improvement over the vomit color palette of the past.

Comment: While we're at changing colors, why not use [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized)'s `#859900` green?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a CSS bug. It's squashed now.

Comment: you have stolen the best ever color and replaced it with a dummy one.

Comment: There really should be a script to automatically grant a diamond to SE senior product designers posting on this meta.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi And take it away if their CSS is buggy.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Rome wasn't built in a day and new designers inherit style sheets and all their imperfections.

Comment: I was being facetious; your work on improving the site designs is appreciated.

Comment: I know, and thank you. I just long for a day when there are no bug reports and all CSS is perfectly in order.

Answer (score 10):

This grave color violation is indeed a bad sign.

As part of a secret plot to take over our profile and move our cheese, a covert file has been precached on all of our machines. It is called *css*.

Make no mistake, this is only the first step.

<sub><sub>[Help us test the shiny new "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features)</sub></sub>

too satire;didn't read

The green will make more sense when the rest of the new profile page is implemented as it is now one of the shades in the color scheme. Pastel colors are the new big thing.

Answer (score -3):

## I ADORE THIS NEW COLOR PLEASE LEAVE IT AND CHANGE NOTHING

[image]

Comment: I don't mind whether they change it, but I'd be curious to learn why they chose it for M.SO, as it doesn't seem to fit the existing color scheme of anything here.