# Profile page is squished - edit/flag/votes stats are wrapping and look bad

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, profile-page

I know the new design has adjusted some things and that some of the sections can expand to relatively unknown widths, but I believe the below is an unintended consequence of this that can be improved:

[image: Squished profile page]

Seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh?tab=topactivity

1. These lines should really not be wrapped.
2. This superfluous whitespace can be minimized to allow for the space needed to show the 1. lines on a single line.

Alternatively/additionally, the badge elements are pretty big, even if you allow for Jon Skeet-levels of badges. They could be thinned up a bit, in my opinion.

This question was spawned from the comments under the question here: 

[The new theme has a lot of space between impact and bottom parts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351380/the-new-theme-has-a-lot-of-space-between-impact-and-bottom-parts)

Comment: And what is with that fluorescent green color in the meters? Sheesh, [I thought we got the green issues ironed out a long time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287258/whats-up-with-this-green)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>This is [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The previous boxes used a custom layout. This has been removed in favor of a more uniform grid system.</strike>

---

#### Update

First, I'm sorry for my initial response. I shouldn't have been so quick to dismiss the request. Thinking further about it, you're not asking for the box to be much bigger—maybe 20 pixels or so. I cannot re-define a column's width, but there are other avenues I can explore.

After some testing, here's how the Impact box can be made bigger:

- The Reputation and Badges boxes will get slightly smaller
- The gutters in-between the boxes will be slightly reduced as well.

This will allow the Impact box to grow and allow the lines to not wrap. It will create some trapped white space on the right side of the Impact box, but I'm fine with that if you are.

This is how the boxes will look now:

[image: New widths]

This has been pushed to production and is now live.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes here are that while it may be `status-bydesign` -  people are probably wondering why that bit can't be made a little wider when it looks like there's potential space on the left...

Comment: I understand that it's by design, which is why I did not tag this as a [meta-tag:bug], but rather a [meta-tag:feature-request]. An appropriate response would be [meta-tag:status-declined] with some reasoning as to why you want a scrunched activity page.

Comment: Just making the 3rd box ~20px wider would solve the problem.. But apparently your fancy uniform grid system does not allow that..

Comment: This is what software developers call a "regression". You implemented a new system behind the scenes, but the results are worse than before. Not only did I downvote to express disagreement with this change, but I also downvoted because this is barely even an answer (it lacks any sort of rationale for why this change was made, and just sort of assumes that the change was beneficial).

Comment: From -1 to +1 for the change in response :)

Comment: So much better, thank you. Still wraps large helpful flags counts, but I can deal with that.

Comment: Thanks for revisiting this, @Hynes